# how to validate field name in kohana include whitespace?

Tags: kohana

i want to verify my field name which only take alphabetic and whitespace.
`$post->add_rules('name','required','alpha')` // it doesn't work with whitespace
How do i make it work with whitespace but not include number. eg Jonh cena

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression for this, eg `/^[a-z ]+$/i`.

I'm not sure where you get the `add_rules()` syntax from, but you'll find an example on how to implement this [in the 3.3 documentation](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/orm/examples/simple#model).

Okay, this is Kohana 2 syntax. Reading the [docs](http://docs.kohanaphp.com/libraries/validation), you should be able to do it like this

```
$post->add_rules('name','required','alpha_space');
```

And add the `alpha_space()` method to the [`valid`](http://docs.kohanaphp.com/helpers/valid) helper using the regular expression mentioned above.

```
public static alpha_space($text) {
    return preg_match("/^[a-z ]+$/i", $text);
}
```